# How to enter text into a textfield in a web view using UIAutomation

Tags: ios, iphone, uiwebview, ui-automation, ios-ui-automation

My iOS app has a log-in page with username and password textfields. These text fields are in a web view. I am trying to automate the log-in process with `UIAutomation`. I know that working with content in a web view with `UIAutomation` is tricky. I am able to tap into the text fields using `target.tap({x:100, y:200});` but I want to have `UIAutomation` enter text after the field has been tapped. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like:

1. Get the reference to the webview

   ```
   var webView=window.scrollViews()[0].webViews()[0];
   ```
2. Tap the textView that you want to edit:

   ```
   webView.textFields()[0].tap();
   ```
3. Use the keyboard

   ```
   UIATarget.localTarget().frontMostApp().keyboard().typeString("text");
   ```

You can use: `webView.logElementTree()` to find out your webview.

Comment: This works. It's how I do it, although I have my own little framework to make it easier.

Comment: One important caveat - you need to make sure you disable the hardware keyboard, or the software keyboard will never show up

Hardware ➜ Keyboard ➜ Connect Hardware Keyboard

(Toggle to OFF)

Also, I seem to need a delay between the tap() and typeString()

Comment: alue of type 'WKWebView' has no member 'textFields'

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is quite possible but instead of going through the position of the text field, I'd suggest going through the id/name of the text field. Another approach is to traverse the application window.

Try following this apple's documentation - http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/UsingtheAutomationInstrument/UsingtheAutomationInstrument.html

This will give you a head start and many other ideas.

Comment: I'd like to do this, but any of the methods available (such as `withName()`) do not seem to work with textfields within UIWebView's. Any suggestions?