# How can I automate test HTML5 elements in the UIAWebView in Instrument?

Tags: html, ui-automation, xcode-instruments

I am trying to automate the test of a mobile app, which is HTML5 embedded in Native app frame. I used the following code to get the elements in Instrument

```
UIALogger.logStart("Log elements in the landing page");
UIATarget.localTarget().logElementTree();
UIALogger.logPass("done");
```

And it will show the HTML5 component as UIAWebView. But for example, if there is a link in the HTML, and I want to click, I can only know it by the position. Is there any method that I can call to get the tags in HTML5?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14760746/how-to-enter-text-into-a-textfield-in-a-web-view-using-uiautomation an answer shows the exacts steps to take.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such menthod, you will get elements with    `target.logElementTree();`    as you used. If elements are native elements, you can use them with predefined methods like    `buttons()`    or    `links()`    else you will have to use them specifying position (xy coordinates) only. This problem always exists with Hybrid apps.

Comment: thanks for the information. How about programming the elements  accessibility in Xcode? Will that help?

Comment: I dont have much knowledge about Xcode programming, but this problem is not regarding element accessibility. This is because all the elements are present in web-view (HTML5 contents). Hence they are not recognized as native elements (for which we can use direct/predefined methods as I mentioned earlier).

Comment: Thanks Sandesh! I think you are right. After exploring it for a while, I realized part of HTML elements, like textFields/links/buttons, have been mapped to iOS native elements. While other, I would think table, are left with staticText. However, they are still recognizable if I use the staticText name. It's kind of a substitution to use coordinate, but I would think it's a little bit more manipulatable.